# ARC: Analyzer warnings with Objective-C code using core foundation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation, clang-static-analyzer

Using the analyzer on some Objective-C | Cocoa / Core Foundation code, I got a few error that I can't fix because I don't understand them.

**Error #1**:
In an Objective-C class header, I declare this property.

```
@property(readwrite) CFMutableSetRef gClients;
```

In the body, I get the following error:

[image]

**Question:** Why is that a leak ? I store it in a property and dispose of it later. I thought ARC knew how to deal with CF "objects".

**Error #2:**
Later on, I have this error when releasing the object:

[image]

**Question:** How can I take those two Analyzer warnings into account in order to create a code that actually works (self.gClients lives between calls to ClientInitialize and destroyAllClients) but does not get flagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC doesn't manage CF objects without manual intervention. There is work you need to do first.

See http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/22/arc-best-practices-and-pitfalls/ at "ARC and toll-free bridging". There are special casting tricks with `(__bridge_transfer)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you suggest I do? `gClients` is declared as: `@property(readwrite) CFMutableSetRef gClients;` self.gClients = (__bridge_retained)CFSetCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL); leads to an error.

Comment: `__bridge_retained` is a type modifier, like `volatile` or `const`. Try `(__bridge_retained CFMutableSetRef)`. Did you read the article? It's spelled out pretty explicitly there.

Comment: `__bridge_retained` is the opposite of what you and @Adrien want here. That will retain the object *again*, when it's already retained by the Create function that returned it. You want `__bridge_transfer`, which tells ARC “deal with this for me, will you?”. (This is mentioned in the article you linked to.)